# Is there a way to pass specific parameter to function(without order) in js?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

Let's say I have the following function:

```
function fun(a,b) {
    if(a) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(a);
        // some other code
    }
    if(b) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(b);
        // some other code, not necessary same as above
    }
}
```

Now I know that I can call the above function like this:

```
fun(1,2) // a=1, b=2
fun()    // a=b=undefined
fun(1)   // a=1, b=undefined
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
fun(2)   // a=undefined, b=2
```

I want to pass only one param **which is assigned to b and not a**.
 
In **c#** it can be done like this:

```
fun(b: 2) // assign b=2
```

So is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

An approach that I have in mind is
Instead of passing two arguments pass one object that contains the arguments.
Something like this:

```
function fun(obj) {
    if(obj.a) {
        console.log(obj.a);
        // some other code
    }
    if(obj.b) {
        console.log(obj.b);
        // some other code, not necessary same as above
    }
}
```

Using the above I can pass specific params only.

But is there any approach which will **not contain any modification** in the function.

**Note:-** I don't want to pass null or undefined as the first argument and then pass the second argument.

Comment: fun(undefined, 2)   // a=undefined, b=2

Comment: Even theoretically, how would you differentiate between `fun(1)`, which you want to assign to `a`, and `fun(2)`, which you want to assign to `b`? Using an object is by far the best approach (destructure the parameters for less syntax noise).

Comment: I pretty much use object params all the time now, so much more flexible / extendable.  And with all the new JS features like array/object destructuring & default values makes it really tidy.  It also makes callee code self documenting.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have named parameters like Python, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do here, is to pass an options `object` as param of your `function`, where you can specify `a` and `b` as `keys` for your `options` object.

There are several JavaScript frameworks that uses similar approach especially when building modules.

This is how should be your function:

```
function fun(options) {
    if(options.a) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(options.a);
        // some other code
    }
    if(options.b) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(options.b);
        // some other code, not necessary same as above
    }
}
```

And as examples of call you can do:

```
fun({b: 2})
fun({a:1, b: 3})
fun({a: "a string"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closure` for this. This way, you won't have to modify your original `function`.

```js
function fun(a,b) {
    if(a) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(a);
        // some other code
    }
    if(b) {  //condition can be different
        console.log(b);
        // some other code, not necessary same as above
    }
}

function func(a) {
  return function(b) {
    fun(a,b);
  }
}

func()(2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how you can achieve the result without specifically assigning the `undefined` value:

```js
function fun(obj) {
  console.log(`a=${obj.a}, b=${obj.b}`)
};

fun({b: 2});
```

Comment: OP has mentioned that he does not want to pass null or undefined

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings Thanks for mentioning. Working on it!

Comment: And what's new in your answer, you just made an edit to take the solution on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52110181/3669624)?

Comment: @chŝdk I don't usually look at other's answers before correcting / answering mine.

Comment: @KaranDhir Oh, that's great !! But you should do that, it's the first rule in SO.

Comment: @chŝdk ah! Thanks for reminding :)